# Siteground SQL Database to Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, hosting, powerbi-datasource

I would like to connect my SQL Database on Siteground Hosting to Power BI through the SQL Server connection. However, I need to get the following information which I am not sure where to get:

1. Siteground Database Credentials in the format: servername:portname
2. Username & Password (which I have)

And finally, when I inserted the IP Address in item no.1, the error received is as below:

[image]

Based on the error above, I figured it could be either: 
(i) the IP address I have inserted is wrong; or
(ii) I need to allow remote access to my database on Siteground CPanel:[image]

If item (ii) is the reason for the error, in order to allow PowerBI to access the database, I would need to insert the IP Address of my PowerBI Online which I do not know how to get

I need assistance basically connecting my PowerBI application to my SQL Database created on my hosting account Siteground

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Siteground control panel suggest that the database is MySQL - your are trying to connect to a SQL Server database. They are not the same thing which is probably why it doesn't work.

Try using the MySQL connector for Power BI

Comment: Thank you. Will try the above of moving to microsoft Azure and connecting from there.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Martin Cairney told you, the connector that you are using is wrong - Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products, which are not compatible. First change the connector.

The list of IP addresses is something dynamic. There is no guarantee, that Power BI will try to connect to your database from a single IP address only, nor that this IP address will stay the same for a long time. If you go this way, you should maintain this on a weekly basis and monitor for changes. The list of IP addresses can be downloaded from these json files:

- Public: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519
- US Gov: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57063
- Germany: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57064
- China: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57062

They are updated weekly.

Better solution is to move your database to Azure (e.g. [Azure MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/) service or MySQL installed in [Virtual Machine in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/)) or to migrate to another data source.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this solution. If I were to move the Azure MySQL, will this make things easier when I connect to other databases later? Also, how do i run python scripts on the database? 
Do I do it within PowerBI or is there a way to run python scripts on a database on the Azure Database before feeding the data to PowerBI?

Comment: See Azure Databricks and Datafactory